# Insertion Loss & Return Loss - GSML2 Link

Tags: loss

I have a GSML2 Link specification connecting Serializer and Deserializer via coax.

While performing the SI analysis, I had a few doubts.

In the deserializer datasheet, we have forward channel of 3Gbps/6Gbps and for reverse channel, we have 1.5Gbps/187Gbps.

The analysis is plotted as : Inserting/Return Loss Vs Frequency.

How should the graph look for the GSML2 Specification?
How to understand the return loss and insertion loss while performing the SI analysis?

If the return loss fails (falls below the GSML2 specification curve @ SI Analysis plot) at a frequency, say 150MHz, does this imply that, this loss, will disturb my reverse channel data (as my reverse channel will communicate at 187Gbps) ?

And If the return loss fails (falls below the GSML2 specification curve @ SI Analysis plot) at a frequency, say 400MHz (greater than 187Gbps), does this imply that, this loss, will **NOT** disturb my reverse channel data (as my reverse channel will communicate at 187Gbps) ?

If I am completely wrong, help to understand with respect to Serdes and Return/Insertion loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a proprietary [SerDes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SerDes) technology as far as i know.

You'd better check with Maxim people.